# How to install Hipchat Server on CentOS 6?

Tags: deployment, centos, centos6, hipchat

In my deep dive into the CentOS terminal, I was able to install and setup Jira, Confluence, and Bitbucket servers.  However, the Hipchat Server seems to be based on something completely different.

Is there a step by step guide to installing Hipchat; From what's needed (dependencies) to installing (which I'm not even sure is part of the process) to seeing it work (log-in, etc.)?

Atlassian's official guide is written in such a way, that I look at it confused - as if it's a riddle that will never be solved. lol

Answer (score 1):

By HipChat4, I'm assuming you refer to the HipChat Client. If so, have you tried the instructions [outlined here](https://buildingtents.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/installing-hipchat-4-on-fedorarhelcentosel-7/)?

```
sudo bash -c ‘cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/hipchat.repo << EOF_hipchat
[atlassian-hipchat]
name=Atlassian Hipchat
baseurl=https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-yum-client/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF_hipchat’

sudo yum update

sudo yum install hipchat4
```

If what you're trying to install is the server, then keep in mind that HipChat Server is only supported on AWS (via the Atlassian provided AMI), or as a VM for private datacenters (via the Atlassian provided OVA). You can't install HipChat Server directly on a Linux box.

If your OS can run a virtualization platform (e.g. VirtualBox) then you can download the OVA from https://www.hipchat.com/server#get-hipchat-server, import it, start your VM and configure it. More thorough instructions are [available here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/hc/deploying-hipchat-server-609944387.html).

Comment: I have edited out the "4".  And the "Official Guide" is the "thorough instructions" that isn't remotely understood.

The problem here is that I'm trying to install Hipchat Server on a CentOS VPS - so the idea of running a VM on a server strikes me like "the paint brush trying to paint itself."  So, it's my current trip down the rabbit hole.

I'm under the impression that this is a Hipchat Server, you install on your server, to use your own Hipchat specificially intended not to be a Cloud solution, but a hosted solution you setup like Jira, Confluence, and Bitbucket.

Comment: Because the instructions on how to install it seem to be about running an interface, and I'm working with a clean VPS.  Not understanding the sense of setting up a virtual server on an actual server and pretending to be a server on a server.  I'm lost.

Comment: @SteveVentimiglia HipChat Server is only supported on AWS (installed via AMI) or as an OVA that requires a virtualization platform (e.g. VirtualBox). You can't  currently install it directly on your OS. I updated the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.